# Python: Error al almacenar multiples valores de una tupla en un Query

Tags: python

Estoy intentando crear una función que me permita meter a modo de tupla los string de "piezas" en un query de SQLite. Para ello he creado anteriormente una base de datos que almacenan los valores de Piezas y Ordenes.
Después he creado esta función, que es donde tengo problemas.

Los modulos que importo son peewee, la carpeta donde creé los modelos con los que se crearon las tablas en SQLite y datetime para la fecha:

```
         from peewee import DoesNotExist
         from Proyecto_final.Proyecto_models import Piezas, Ordenes
         from datetime import datetime
```

y esta est la función:

```
    def orden_compra ():
        Vendedor_nombre = input('¿Quién eres?: ')
        numero = int(input('¿Número de artículos?: '))
        lista_piezas=[]
        for i in range (0, numero):
            while True:
                pieza_nombre = input('Nombre de la pieza a comprar: ')
                try:
                    pieza = Piezas.get(Piezas.Nombre == pieza_nombre)
                    break
                except DoesNotExist:
                    print('Esta pieza no existe actualmente en el sistema, '
                        'por favor ingresa un nombre correcto.')
            ID = input('ID de la compra: ')
            for precio in Piezas.select().where(Piezas.Nombre == pieza_nombre):
                precio_ordenes = (precio.Precio)
            precio_ordenes+=precio_ordenes
            pieza=str(pieza)
            lista_piezas.append(pieza)
            Ordenes.create(ID_compra_ordenes=ID, Fecha_compra_ordenes=datetime.now(),
                          Vendedor_ordenes=Vendedor_nombre, Piezas_ordenes = pieza_2,
                          Precio_ordenes=lista_piezas)
            print('Pieza vendida satisfactoreamente')
```

La función me pide un nombre y el número de artículos para registrar, mediante un loop me pide el nombre de la pieza y lo comprueba si existe ya previamente en la base de datos creada anteriormente (tabla Precio).

Si es así me pide más opciones del producto si no, me pide de nuevo que meta un nombre válido.
Cuando existe una concordancia entre el objeto a registrar y el que está almacenado en la base de datos de Precio obtiene el precio de esa tabla y va sumando los precios acorde con el número total de productos adquiridos.

Mi problema es que esta función registra objeto a objeto y me gustaría que el total de objetos que una persona registre se queden almacenados a modo de tupla. Sin embargo al ejecutar el código entero me da este error:

```
           Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "C:/Users/apl00.DESKTOP-IGEQ9D2/Desktop/CloudStation/Proyectos/Python/Módulos/Proyecto_final/Proyecto_main.py", line 214, in <module>
orden_compra()
         File "C:/Users/apl00.DESKTOP-IGEQ9D2/Desktop/CloudStation/Proyectos/Python/Módulos/Proyecto_final/Proyecto_main.py", line 112, in orden_compra
Ordenes.create(ID_compra_ordenes=ID, Fecha_compra_ordenes=datetime.now(),
          TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'
```

¿En qué estoy fallando?
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: No se nada sobre el modulo que usas, pero por lo que veo, en el comando abajo de todo, en `ordenes.create` le pasas una lista a `precio_ordenes`. Y supongo que no quieres pasar una lista a un importe.

Comment: Gracias @Dante S. por tu respuesta, ya he modificado la pregunta añadiendo información sobre los módulos. Si, quiero pasar la lista generada a un importe total con todos los productos en forma de tupla. ¿En que estoy fallando?

Comment: De nada! No me referia a eso, me referia a que no conozco sobre los modulos, pero gracias igual, seguro le servira a alguien mas. ¿Me pasas un ejemplo de lo que contiene `lista_piezas` por favor?

Comment: Cuando ejecuto la función print(lista_piezas) después de añadir los valores requeridos que se describen en el post me devuelve este output ['1', '1']

Comment: ¿Tu objetivo es crear por ejemplo algo asi?:

Comment: Vendedor ----> pieza1

Comment: Vendedor----> pieza2

Comment: No, venta 1 hecha por el vendedor 1, con el número de referencia xxx, que ha vendido tanto (tupla) con un importe de xxx

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116873/discussion-between-dante-s-and-adrian-p-l).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bien, tras un intenso debate con @Dante S. he llegado a la conclusión que la construcción de la base de datos estaba mal hecha. Había hipervinculado el nombre de las piezas con la tabla de las ordenes por eso me salían números. Lo he cambiado a formato chartfield() y ya se almacena en forma de tupla. Gracias de todas maneras @Dante S.